# Calling a function everytime user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I have the following function, I want to get called everytime, user types something in the `typeahead` input field.

```
function getAllActiveUsers() {
    var userList = $('#usersTable').jqGrid('getGridParam').userData;
    var userNames = {};
    if(userList) {
        // Return the list  of all active users
        $(userList).each(function() {
            if(this.userStatus != 1) {
                // If the user is verified
                // Could be active/inactive
                userNames.user = this.username;
            }
        });
    }
    return JSON.stringify(userNames);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="the-basics">
   <input class="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="User List">
</div>
```

I have been browsing through, the [examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), but do not understand how to implement this functionality.

**Edit**:

Why it doesn't work when I initialize as :

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source : getAllActiveUsers
});
```

Comment: call the function on `$('.typeahead').on('keyup',getAllActiveUsers())` try this

Comment: What kind of typeahead are you using? You are referring to typehead.js, but something tells me you are using a different one?

Comment: What does `getAllActiveUsers` return?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.typeahead').keyup(function(){
       getAllActiveUsers();
   });
});
```

Comment: Why use an anonymous function? That's redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .keyup jquery function

```
$( ".typeahead" ).keyup(function() {
  getAllActiveUsers();
});
```

Comment: Why use an anonymous function? That's redundancy.

Comment: You're right. Anonymous function can be just replaced by the function that needs to be executed.  But it is easier to read.

Comment: It doesn't work. I am trying to use `twitter's` typeahead.

Comment: I haven't used that plugin, but I suppose you are providing data in a wrong format to it.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the reference you gave you can specify the class `.typeahead` inside the id `#the-basics`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
    //code here;
  }
}
```

Since the page can't be manipulated safely until the document is ready you should be using `$(document).ready`.
Also, try to use your browser console and check if you can reach `$('#the-basics .typeahead')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Keyup which gets triggered when a key is released.

```
$( ".typeahead" ).on('keyup',function() {
  getAllActiveUsers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your text box coming dynamically then you should try

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".typeahead" , function() {
  getAllActiveUsers();
});
```

try this and let us know if its works or not.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible

```
var getAllActiveUsers = function(q, cb, cb2) {
  // cb for sync, cb2 for async
  var userList = $('#usersTable').jqGrid('getGridParam').userData;
  var filterted = /* whatever you want to do with q */;
  cb(filtered);
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    /* Options */
},
{
    source : getAllActiveUsers
});
```